# Getting certain information from string

Tags: python

I'm new to python as was wondering how I could get the `estimatedWait` and `routeName` from this string.

```
{
  "lastUpdated": "07:52",
  "filterOut": [],
  "arrivals": [
    {
      "routeId": "B16",
      "routeName": "B16",
      "destination": "Kidbrooke",
      "estimatedWait": "due",
      "scheduledTime": "06: 53",
      "isRealTime": true,
      "isCancelled": false
    },
    {
      "routeId":"B13",
      "routeName":"B13",
      "destination":"New Eltham",
      "estimatedWait":"29 min",
      "scheduledTime":"07:38",
      "isRealTime":true,
      "isCancelled":false
    }
  ],
  "serviceDisruptions":{
    "infoMessages":[],
    "importantMessages":[],
    "criticalMessages":[]
  }
}
```

And then save this to another string which would be displayed on the `lxterminal` of the raspberry pi 2.  I would like only the 'routeName' of B16 to be saved to the string.  How do I do that?

Comment: Are you sure this is the whole string? Because there are brackets missing at the end. If this is valid JSON you can deserialize this into a python object: `obj = json.loads(yourstring)`

Comment: There is more. This is the while string.

Comment: {"lastUpdated":"08:09","filterOut":[],"arrivals":[{"routeId":"B13","routeName":"B13","destination":"New Eltham","estimatedWait":"1 min","scheduledTime":"07:10","isRealTime":true,"isCancelled":false},{"routeId":"B13","routeName":"B13","destination":"New Eltham","estimatedWait":"29 min","scheduledTime":"07:38","isRealTime":true,"isCancelled":false}],"serviceDisruptions":{"infoMessages":[],"importantMessages":[],"criticalMessages":[]}}

Comment: And what would I do with this python object if I want the routeName?

Comment: Please just edit your question to update informations like this. Which `estimatedWait` and `routeName` do you need? Just the first?

Comment: If an answer helped you, please mark it as answer :) Or write a comment what you are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to deserialise the object and then use the index to access the data you want.

To find only the `B16` entries you can filter the arrivals list.

```
import json
obj = json.loads(json_string)

# filter only the b16 objects
b16_objs = filter(lambda a: a['routeName'] == 'B16',  obj['arrivals'])

if b16_objs:
    # get the first item
    b16 = b16_objs[0]
    my_estimatedWait = b16['estimatedWait']
    print(my_estimatedWait)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.find() to get the indices of those value identifiers
and extract them.

Example:

```
def get_vaules(string):
    waitIndice = string.find('"estimatedWait":"')
    routeIndice = string.find('"routeName":"')
    estimatedWait = string[waitIndice:string.find('"', waitIndice)]
    routeName = string[routeIndice:string.find('"', routeIndice)]
    return estimatedWait, routeName
```

Or you could just deserialize the json object (highly recommended)

```
import json

def get_values(string):
    jsonData = json.loads(string)
    estimatedWait = jsonData['arrivals'][0]['estimatedWait']
    routeName = jsonData['arrivals'][0]['routeName']
    return estimatedWait, routeName
```

[Parsing values from a JSON file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python)